# XAMPP (WIN7) port change and vhosts

Tags: apache, xampp, port, vhosts

I've decided to change the ports for Apache to clear up some conflicts with other applications, and maybe even give IIS a shot in the future. I've run into the problem described below.

The basic context:

```
WIN 7 x64
XAMPP 1.7.4 (Apache 2.2.17, MySQL 5.5.8, PHP 5.3.5)
```

So I've changed the default Apache port from 80 to 8080, by changing this in the httpd.conf:

```
Listen 8080 (was Listen 80)
ServerName localhost:8080 (was ServerName localhost)
```

In my vhosts file I have:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
```

And several virtual hosts defined like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot "somepath"
    ServerName servername
    <directory "somepath">
        usual stuff here
    </directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access the virtual host using the servername defined above it does not work without explicitly specifying the port:

```
servername:8080
```

It would also seem that the port defined in the vhosts file does not make any difference, whatever I tried (80, 8080, nothing), it allways requires the port to be given with the server name.

phpinfo() says:

```
SERVER_PORT: 8080
```

Apache error logs do not show any errors.

I guess I'm wondering if this is normal behaviour, or there is something I overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

The 80 port is default for browsers so that's why you don't need to access servername:80. In your case it's normal to acces server like this : servername:8080

Answer (score 0):

If your want to access localhost without specify the port number in the URL
 `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost:8080`.

- Open **Xampp Control Panel**
- Go to **Config** ► **Service and Port Settings** ► **Apache**
- Replace the **Main Port** value ​​with `8080`.
- Save **Service settings**
- Save **Configuration of Control Panel**
- Restart the Apache Server
  [image: xampp apache setting port]